# Linklist Structure (passing strucure pointer to a function )

Tags: c++, function, pointers, structure

I made a structure  for link list , Then declared its pointer globally, Then made two functions to add node, and to display list.
All was working fine when I declared structure pointer globally,

But then I declared pointer in main function and changed the code according to it due to my need. but now when I compile and run the exe. It gives me xxxx.exe stopped working !

Tldr : passed structure pointer to a function but its not working !

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 struct node {

 int data;
 node *adr;
 };


 void insertate(int n, struct node *h)
 {

    struct node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->data=n;
    temp->adr=NULL;


    if(h==NULL)
    {   
        h=temp;    
    }

    else
    {
        struct node *q;
        q= new node;
        q=h;
        while(q->adr!=NULL)
        {
            q=q->adr;      
        }
        q->adr=temp;   

    } 

 }


 void  print(struct node *h)
 {

    struct node *c=h;
    while(c!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<c->data;
        c=c->adr;   
        cout<<endl;     
    }          
 }      


 int main()
 {   
    struct node *a;

    insertate(5,a);
    insertate(4,a);
    insertate(31,a);
    insertate(32,a);
    insertate(34,a);
    insertate(36,a);

    print(a);

    return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Allocate your head node first in main()

```
struct node *a = new node;
```

Then try passing by reference:

```
insertate(5, &a);
```

You will also need to update your method definitions, instead of *h it will be **h like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  int data;
  node *adr;
};

void insertate(int n, struct node **h) {
  struct node *temp;
  temp = new node;
  temp->data=n;
  temp->adr=NULL;

  if(h==NULL) {
    *h=temp;
  }
  else
  {
    struct node *q;
    q= new node;
    q=*h;
    while(q->adr!=NULL)
    {
      q=q->adr;
    }
    q->adr=temp;
  }
}

void print(struct node **h)
{
  struct node *c=*h;
  while(c!=NULL)
  {
    cout<<c->data;
    c=c->adr;
    cout<<endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  struct node *a = new node;
  a->data = 0;      // Set this to initial head value
  a->adr = NULL;
  insertate(5, &a);
  insertate(4, &a);
  insertate(31, &a);
  insertate(32, &a);
  insertate(34, &a);
  insertate(36, &a);
  print(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

also when you access h inside the method since it is a pointer to a pointer you will need to dereference so notice:

```
q = *h;
```

You can test it by clicking the link below, you may want to update your print function as to not print out the head value which is 0 right now:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJNboMwEIX3nGKqShVBidS/dAPOCaLuegDLngZLYMA2zaLi7NT2kBBSFsj2m/H7Rs@Itt2dhBjHR6VF1UuEQjXWGeT1Iemt0ifQvEbbcoFgncyTxFd74UA3vvk3AVDageSO534fxYxLkyeDb/1plPR1i8Zxh2no1Fu4NciychNdFqLDug12YQUGGs@xcJF2h8Bjej57Ivv8Oh490w/0nZYsHskaICvZxXLwH1YW/UK1BbjLo9YtmUHIStqdS1Vh2kXkA0GiTmahk2rUPdBtGnAeYZiiaY2PJL3PI/mXh5jwBBczl6ii6V1RCIqFwIKJmzGoAbWsrvzwFjVXOl2Jn99lPr/gfgtPfLPU3le0t5c18XVNXL3@cRUpoulg0PVGw7P/u2Ac/wA)

By doing it this way we allocate the head pointer on the heap by using the new operator in the main function. Some people give the head pointer a dummy variable, but in this case I decided it was easier to initialize in the main function. Now that we have a pointer to the memory in the heap we can pass it to our functions using its address (aka & operator). This creates a pointer to a pointer (**h) which is its type. Just like with regular pointers, we need to dereference it in order to access its values, that is why we use *h when we want to access the head pointer.

Comment: I tried declaring a structure variable then passing " &structurevariable " in function but its still same !

Comment: @irfanadil what do you mean by "we can't pass pointer address" is that the requirements or something?

Comment: Just Executed Updated code now its just showig black console window,
Not printing anything !

Comment: @irfanadil here I changed it again to add a default value to the head, see if that works

Comment: I am using dev c++ 5.11 TDM-GCC 4.9.2..Which should I use?
And I just can't understand why its showing 0 as first value

Comment: @irfanadil it is showing 0 as the first value because that is what the head pointer is being initialized with right now in main(), you can change it to 5 and remove the first insertate function so that your list begins with 5. Are you seeing the output now?

Comment: Yes , Now its working In my Compiler, Would you please explain, Why we changed *h to ** h . and why its necessary to initialize (node pointer )its first  with some thing?

Comment: Ok, Does you got something skype? discord?

Comment: @irfanadil sorry I can't right now, got to go but if the answer works for you please accept :)

Comment: No man ! Why Would I ! well I just raised the vote in upward !